# Can't type danish character 'Å' in Chrome on MacOS

Tags: google-chrome, characters, typing

On my macbook I can type danish characters using the classic:

1. option ' = æ
2. option o = ø
3. option a = å
4. option shift ' = Æ
5. option shift o = Ø
6. option shift a = Å

All six works in pages, Firefox and iTerm.
Only the first five works just fine in chrome.
So my problem is that I can't type 'Å' in chrome.
My language settings is US and the keyboard is also US.

Comment: I reported this back to Google from the "Report an issue ..." menu in Chrome.
(no reply from Google)

Comment: Also posted here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/A1IIPxBY174;context-place=forum/chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dark Reader extension have a keyboard shortcut by default that maps option+shift+A

You can see and manage keyboard shortcuts in Chrome extensions here:  chrome://extensions/shortcuts

Just change the shortcut or delete it.